Getting The prefix "jxb" for element "jxb:bindings" is not bound exception after migrating to jaxb3/java21
While migrating a service to java21 and jaxb3.0, the class generation for xjb file from a wsdl is giving a 'org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; XXX The prefix "jxb" for element "jxb:bindings" is not bound.'
Not sure if the problem is the file it self or the way the plugin is configured.
The final error for the maven build is:
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.jvnet.jaxb:jaxb-maven-plugin:4.0.0:generate (WSDL) on project project-api: Unable to parse input schema(s). Error messages should have been provided. -> [Help 1]
The cause of the exception is the class generation by the plugin.
Main exception:
[ERROR] Error while parsing schema(s).Location [ file:/C:/project/project-api/src/main/resources/bindings/wsBinding.xjb{8,52}].
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: The prefix "jxb" for element "jxb:bindings" is not bound.
... (long stacktrace)
following the exception:
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; systemId: file:/C:/project/project-api/src/main/resources/bindings/wsBinding.xjb; lineNumber: 8; columnNumber: 52; The prefix "jxb" for element "jxb:bindings" is not bound.
... (more stacktrace)
Here are the binding in question:
original bindings (jaxb2, java8):
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jxb:bindings version="1.0"
              xmlns:jxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb"
              xmlns:xjc="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb/xjc"
              xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
              xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/"
              xmlns:annox="http://annox.dev.java.net"
              jxb:extensionBindingPrefixes="annox">

<jxb:globalBindings>
    <xjc:serializable uid="7702"/>
    <xjc:javaType adapter="com.cie.project.adapter.LocalDateAdapter" name="java.time.LocalDate"
                  xmlType="xsd:date"/>
</jxb:globalBindings>

   <jxb:bindings schemaLocation="../clients/wsBinding.wsdl" node="/wsdl:definitions/wsdl:types/xsd:schema">
    <jxb:bindings node="//xsd:complexType[@name='theRequest']">
        <jxb:class name="TheRequestType"/>
        <annox:annotateClass>@javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement(name="theRequest")</annox:annotateClass>
      </jxb:bindings>

      <jxb:bindings node="//xsd:complexType[@name='theResponse']">
        <jxb:class name="TheResponseType"/>
        <annox:annotateClass>@javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement(name="theResponse")</annox:annotateClass>
      </jxb:bindings>
    </jxb:bindings>
</jxb:bindings>

new updated binding with the error (java21, jaxb3)
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jxb:bindings version="1.0"
              xmlns:jaxb="https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/jaxb"
              xmlns:xjc="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb/xjc"
              xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
              xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/"
              xmlns:annox="http://annox.dev.java.net"
              jxb:extensionBindingPrefixes="annox">

    <jxb:globalBindings>
        <xjc:serializable uid="7702"/>
        <xjc:javaType adapter="com.cie.project.adapter.LocalDateAdapter" name="java.time.LocalDate"
                      xmlType="xsd:date"/>
    </jxb:globalBindings>

    <jxb:bindings schemaLocation="../clients/wsBinding.wsdl" node="/wsdl:definitions/wsdl:types/xsd:schema">
        <jxb:bindings node="//xsd:complexType[@name='theRequest']">
            <jxb:class name="TheRequestType"/>
            <annox:annotateClass>@jakarta.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement(name="theRequest")</annox:annotateClass>
        </jxb:bindings>

        <jxb:bindings node="//xsd:complexType[@name='theResponse']">
            <jxb:class name="TheResponseType"/>
            <annox:annotateClass>@jakarta.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement(name="theResponse")</annox:annotateClass>
        </jxb:bindings>
    </jxb:bindings>
</jxb:bindings>

Here the jaxbplugin config in maven if it could help
  <plugin>
      <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb</groupId>
      <artifactId>jaxb-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <id>WSDL</id>
        <goals>
          <goal>generate</goal>
        </goals>
      </execution>
    </executions>
    <configuration>
      <schemaLanguage>WSDL</schemaLanguage>
      <generatePackage>com.cie.project.ws</generatePackage>
      <schemaDirectory>${project.basedir}</schemaDirectory>
      <schemaIncludes>
        <include>src/main/resources/clients/*.wsdl</include>
      </schemaIncludes>
      <bindingDirectory>${project.basedir}</bindingDirectory>
      <bindingIncludes>
        <include>src/main/resources/bindings/*.xjb</include>
      </bindingIncludes>
      <verbose>true</verbose>
      <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-plugins</artifactId>
        </plugin>
      </plugins>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>

Note sure if this is related I got a weird warning before these exception:
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: Are you trying to compile a WSDL ?  Support for WSDL is experimental. You may enable it by using the -wsdl option.
EDIT: Answer:
The header for the binding file need to be updated from xmlns:jaxb to xmlns:jxb (from @Laurent Schoelens answer) and need to be version 3.
    <jxb:bindings version="3.0"
          xmlns:jxb="https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/jaxb"
          xmlns:xjc="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb/xjc"
          xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
          xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/"
          xmlns:annox="urn:jaxb.jvnet.org:annox"
          jxb:extensionBindingPrefixes="annox">

Not sure if it related but the plugin needed to include the following plugin to work:
    <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb</groupId>
    <artifactId>jaxb-basics-annotate</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.9</version>


Your binding has a simple error :
<jxb:bindings version="3.0"
              xmlns:jaxb="https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/jaxb"
              xmlns:xjc="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb/xjc"
              xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
              xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/"
              xmlns:annox="http://annox.dev.java.net"
              jxb:extensionBindingPrefixes="annox">

You got jxb:bindings declaration but xmlns:jAxb as declared namespace.
If you still want to use jxb, replace xmlns:jaxb with xmlns:jxb namespace prefix.
And you can also replace the xmlns:annox="http://annox.dev.java.net" with the new annox namespace urn:jaxb.jvnet.org:annox (so with xmlns:annox="urn:jaxb.jvnet.org:annox"). See plugin's migration guide

Thanks, this solved the problem. Note it was missing version 3.0 as well. I must have copied the binding header from somewhere that was working and didn't notice the jxb vs jaxb namespace declaration difference.

Just fixed the version 3.0 header, thanks to your comment :)
